# Screen Recording of a Web Page

Tags: html, node.js, screen-capture

Basically what I wanted to do is add a function that allows user to record his session on a webpage and save it in a video file.Is there any way to do this , using   **NodeJS/Html5/Javscript.**

I was thinking of taking the screenshot of the page at every second and sending it to the server ....but how can I put all those screenshots together so that it looks like an actual **recording session or video**.... or is there any better way to do it?

Comment: I think WebRTC provides features for screensharing/-capturing…

Comment: ah swell,i looked it up.... that might do my work.Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I your case I would state that [WebRTC](http://www.webrtc.org/) will provide you with all the features you need. I think the basic setup includes a lot of servers-stuff too, but all in all it will provide you with all the performance you need to capture the entire screen.